# The future of Google Apps Script User Interface - UiInstance or HTML Service?

Tags: google-apps-script

The situation:
I'm currently creating an advanced Google Apps application which I would like to release later on in the Google Add-On store (It's an Add-On for Google Spreadsheets).

My application has since the beginning been developed using the UiInstance service for creating the User Interface. It  works swell and I'm really happy with the results.

However, if I consult [the Add-On style guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style) this is mentioned:

> Use the add-ons CSS package in your HTML service pages. (And don't use UI service to create a public add-on — it won't look as professional.)

Also, the **UI service** is marked as Experimental in [the Google Apps Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-instance), this might also be a problem for publicly releasing it (can anybody point me in the right direction to ask more information on this?)

The question; Does anybody know about the plans for the UI Service? Might this get deprecated in the (near) future? I've been looking for more information on this but I did not find it. Please keep in mind that your guess is as good as mine.

Should I start recreating my UI with the HTML Service or is there any future for the UI Service?

My personal opinion; I think the UI Service makes it **a lot** easier to create a User Interface, still having the possibility to adjust it as you wish.

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit for Stackoverflow since it's mostly about opinions. As for Google's future plans that is more of a question for Google then the SO community since it would most likely invite conjecture.

Comment: I started with Google Apps Script in may. Because of what I knew from several years ago and UiApp looked familiar to me, I decided to use UiApp. That decision has been wrong. HtmlService definitively is the better choice for various reasons. I'm still developing using UiApp as I consider this version being a prototype, but I will convert it as soon as it is 'ready'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are perfectly right when you say "*your guess is as good as mine*" but I see at least 2 arguments that makes me think HTML Service is the way to go :

1. the "recommendation" about not using UiApp in add-on is not really a recommendation, it's definitely a requirement. They won't approve an add-on build with UiApp (and approval is also a mandatory step)
2. They provide a link to a Google static CSS sheet that will determine the "look and feel" of the add-ons for buttons, fonts and about all graphic elements used in the Ui so that, if ever they feel like changing something in the Ui, they have full control on it and don't rely on each app developer good will to update it. This would not be the case in UiApp of course.

And lastly, they stopped maintaining UiApp and deprecated all methods that were having issues, leaving it "as it is" so I guess the future is - at the least - uncertain...

I fully agree with you that when you know how to use UiApp it is fairly easy but I know also that this is more a personal point of view that not so much people share. If you are a "normal" web developer then HTML and JQuery are certainly more familiar and far more easy to use.

I guess (I know it's just a personal guess ;-) it's time to start your "mutation" to HTML Service, at least if your goal is to publish your apps.

Comment: This is true, HTML services is the future for GApps. But I am facing a lot of issues in jquery. Some codes which works perfectly on local machine doesn't works when I put it on GAS. Even after setting the sandboxmode it fails. Sometime this makes me cry. Any suggestion on this will be much helpful for me.